# Navegação de Registro C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho Dois botões: <kbd>Próximo</kbd> e <kbd>Anterior</kbd> em uma aplicação Windows Forms em C#, estou usando uma instrução SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM aluno LIMIT 1;
```

para MYSQL. Essa instrução pega o 1º registro.

Agora vem o dilema, não estou conseguindo fazer a navegação de registros (trazer todos os alunos).

---

Estou usando esse código:

```
if (Contador < Tabela.Rows.Count - 1){}
```

Mas a variável contador está pegando o segundo registro e não o primeiro.

Comment: Olá. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) como criar uma pergunta clara.

Comment: Acho que fui claro, Preciso clicar no botão próximo e navegar pelo registro da tablea

Comment: Tente melhorar a formatação, mostra as suas tentativas, melhor a sua pergunta de forma a pode ajudar mais utilizadores.

Comment: Talvez isso ajuda, Achei esse código, http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2961/acessando-dados-com-textboxes-e-botoes-de-navegacao.aspx
Só que ele é feito para access como ficara em C# para mysql

Answer (score 1):

Para a navegação, exige-se a consulta trazendo todos os alunos:

```
SELECT * FROM aluno
```

Trazendo apenas um registro, a lista de alunos virá com apenas um registro.

Comment: Tem como me passar em exemplo

Comment: @FabrícioSimoneAlanaMendes Posso sim, mas preciso saber como está sua tela, o que já foi feito até aqui. Inclua esse código na sua pergunta.